# Force prolog to make substitutions in output results

Tags: prolog, output-formatting

In the process of learning Prolog I'm making simple program which given some thing is able to tell what is on the left / right / above / below of that thing.
Code is this:

```
% left_(LeftThing, ToThing)
left_(bicycle, camera).
left_(pencil, clock).
left_(clock, butterfly).
left_(butterfly, fish).

% above_(AboveThing, ToThing)
above_(bicycle, pencil).
above_(camera,  butterfly).

right(X, Y) :-
  left_(Y, X);
  X = (empty).

below(X, Y) :-
  above_(Y, X);
  X = (empty).

left(X, Y) :-
  left_(X, Y);
  X = (empty).

above(X, Y) :-
  above_(X, Y);
  X = (empty).

position(Thing, Left, Right, Above, Below) :-
    left(Left,  Thing),
   right(Right, Thing),
   above(Above, Thing),
   below(Below, Thing), !.
```

Now when I ask for :

`?- position(clock, Left, Right, Above, Below).`

I get an answer:

```
Left = pencil,
Right = butterfly,
Above = Below, Below = empty.
```

While this is perfectly correct answer, I would like Prolog to make full substitutions and give an output in *standard* way:

```
Left = pencil,
Right = butterfly,
Above = empty,
Below = empty.
```

Is there a way to force Prolog doing such substitutions in output without cluttering a lot with program facts and rules ? (err... maybe there is some results formatting option in SWI-Prolog configuration. If not - how to achieve this with minimal code changes ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog returns a most general unifier as a solution when it finds one. Here it is a perfectly standard one and I didn't find [any flag](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.11%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/flags.html%27%29%29) to change this behavior (I might have missed one though, maybe a `toplevel_print_options` custom predicate or something).

That being said, you could roll your own print predicate if you want a prettyprint. It'd allow you to clean your database btw, because here you represent extra stuff from the original problem only to be able to return `empty`, which isn't good from a conception point of view. My take would be:

```
% left(LeftThing, ToThing)
left(  bicycle,   camera).
left(  pencil,    clock).
left(  clock,     butterfly).
left(  butterfly, fish).

% above(AboveThing, ToThing)
above( bicycle,   pencil).
above( camera,    butterfly).

right(X, Y) :-
    left(Y, X).

below(X, Y) :-
    above(Y, X).

print_custom(Y, Pred) :-
    (   call(Pred, X, Y)
     -> true
      ; X = empty),
    format('~w = ~w,~n', [Pred, X]).


position(Thing) :-
    maplist( print_custom(Thing),
             [left, right, above, below] ).
```

Test:

```
?- position(clock).
left = pencil,
right = butterfly,
above = empty,
below = empty,
true.
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a [flag controlling](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2) this behaviour, and internally (see boot/toplevel.pl) join_same_bindings/2 is called unconditionally.

There is an undocumented predicate print_toplevel_variables/0, but the output is not ordered, and contains 'historical' variables unrelated to last query:

```
?- position(clock, Left, Right, Above, Below).
Left = pencil,
Right = butterfly,
Above = Below, Below = empty.

?- print_toplevel_variables.
$Below =    empty
$Above =    empty
$Right =    butterfly
$Left =     pencil
$X =        false
$T =        position(clock,pencil,butterfly,empty,empty)
$Y =        1
false.
```